# How to use BundleConfig in WebSite project

Tags: asp.net, web

ok, that maybe a old question, but i really dont know how to use BundleConfig in website project.
not the webform project or mvc project.

i debug the code. it call the BundleConfig's add  method.
but it not work. something wrong?

this is my code:

add **Global.asax** in Root

add **BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles)** in **Application_Start**

add **BundleConfig.vb** class in **App_Code**

```
Public Class BundleConfig
    Public Shared Sub RegisterBundles(ByVal bundles As BundleCollection)
        bundles.Add(New StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"))
    End Sub
End Class
```

add **Default.aspx**

add **Content/site.css** file.

and something?

OK, i knew what is happend.
i put my css file in Content/css/ folder.
this line:

```
bundles.Add(New StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/css/site.css"))
```

so it not work.
and i change it to

```
bundles.Add(New StyleBundle("~/whatever/css").Include("~/Content/css/site.css"))
```

done.

Answer (score 1):

Try registering the bundles in your Global.asax file by adding this line of code:

```
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

Examine the Bundle.config file, which contains the markup to create CSS style bundles. You can add your own style bundles. e.g:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<bundles version="1.0">
<styleBundle path="~/Content/css"><include path="~/Content/Site.css" /></styleBundle>
</bundles>
```

Now reference it in your page using:

```
<webopt:BundleReference runat="server" Path="~/Content/css" />
```

Comment: oh,sorry. I really do this .
as the webform project. I add all config helper in Application_Start(), and then in the BundleConfig.RegisterBundles, I copy the code from webform project. and just add a little css file.but not woking.

Comment: What actually is the problem? Does it fail to bundle or throws an exception

Comment: what i want is , when i run the website, the BunduleConfig will import css file into html. but it not import.i dont want to write 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/Site.css" />  

in all my page.

Comment: It seems the problem is that the css file exist in the same path used for the Bundle configuration and there seems to be a conflict. Isn't it